# Error: Cannot find module - Working locally but not on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I am running a node application that I cloned from my Heroku container. locally, it runs and the app operates from localhost:3000.

However when I deploy the app using git deploy to heroku, it starts and then immediately crashes. The heroku log is pasted below.

I can't work out why I am getting this error?

I've tried updating npm, deleteing node modules.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm i core-util-is
npm install -g npm@latest
```

The heroku log looks like:

```
2019-06-24T15:35:26.071317+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2019-06-24T15:35:26.071318+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251019+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251023+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251024+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251026+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251027+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './putty'
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251031+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251033+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251034+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251036+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251037+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/auto.js:18:13)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251039+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251040+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251041+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251043+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.251044+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-06-24T15:35:26.259163+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-06-24T15:35:26.259707+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-06-24T15:35:26.261454+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! hello@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2019-06-24T15:35:26.261645+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-06-24T15:35:26.261955+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2019-06-24T15:35:26.262153+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the hello@1.0.0 start script.
2019-06-24T15:35:26.262343+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-06-24T15:35:26.270567+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-06-24T15:35:26.270795+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-06-24T15:35:26.270955+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-06-24T15_35_26_264Z-debug.log
```

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module './putty'` It looks like node can't find your own module './putty'. Are you sure every file have added properly into git?

Comment: Yeah I have done npm install putty to be sure and it's in the package.json under dependencies.

Comment: What is the `"./putty"` module? Does it come from the package from npm install or written by yourself? It's looks like you using npm install to install the putty, and using the local module reference.  You need remove the './' before the putty. If you install the putty from npm install. Otherwise, you need make sure there have a putty module in your relative path "./"

Comment: It is a personal module if it's prepended with ./

Comment: I am not using putty, I assume it's from the clone off heroku. I imagine I need to restart the NPM install and refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted the package.json and node_modules and ran

```
npm init
```

then reinstalled the packages required, it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and in my case was able to resolve by moving the alleged "missing" module from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` in `package.json`. For whatever reason, it didn't matter that it was saved in `devDependencies` locally but caused an error on Heroku until reinstalling as a regular dependency.